# Unable to access the state of ValueNotifier inside the MaterialApp

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been experimenting with `ValueNotifier` in Dart and Flutter and came across an interesting issue.
I defined two custom themes and tried to access them from two different parts of the app using `ValueListenableBuilder`
I am able to correctly get the theme data within the `Container` inside the `App` component. However, it doesn't work with the `MaterialApp`. Please shed some light on why this is happening.

PS: I know there are better ways to manage the theme, I am just experimenting.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _themeManager = ThemeManager();
    return ValueListenableBuilder<ThemeData>(
        valueListenable: _themeManager.theme,
        builder: (context, theme, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            // theme not updating ❌
            theme: theme,
            home: const App(),
          );
        });
  }
}

class Theme {
  static ThemeData primaryTheme =
      ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber, primaryColor: Colors.amber);
  static ThemeData secondaryTheme =
      ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue, primaryColor: Colors.blue);
}

class ThemeManager {
  final ValueNotifier<ThemeData> _theme =
      ValueNotifier<ThemeData>(Theme.primaryTheme);

  ValueNotifier<ThemeData> get theme => _theme;

  void changeTheme(ThemeData theme) {
    _theme.value = theme;
  }
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _themeManager = ThemeManager();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ValueListenableBuilder<ThemeData>(
              valueListenable: _themeManager.theme,
              builder: (context, theme, child) {
                return Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  // theme updating correctly ✔️
                  color: theme.primaryColor,
                );
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _themeManager.theme.value =
                      _themeManager.theme.value == Theme.primaryTheme
                          ? Theme.secondaryTheme
                          : Theme.primaryTheme;
                },
                child: const Text('Toggle Theme')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with two different instances of `ThemeManager`. One in `MyApp` other in the build method of the `App` Widget. On tapping the button, you are only updating the second instance, that's why only the container is being updated. Try to use a single instance of `ThemeManager` or define ThemeManager as a Singleton.

Update ThemeManager as

```
class ThemeManager {
  static ThemeManager? _instance;

  ThemeManager._();

  static ThemeManager get instance => _instance ??= ThemeManager._();

  final ValueNotifier<ThemeData> _theme =
      ValueNotifier<ThemeData>(Theme.primaryTheme);

  ValueNotifier<ThemeData> get theme => _theme;

  void changeTheme(ThemeData theme) {
    _theme.value = theme;
  }
}
```

and get the instance of ThemeManager as

```
    final _themeManager = ThemeManager.instance;
```

Here is the updated code on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=74cd7ea1307d06cdb4506acb4fb211e6).

Comment: great! this was the issue. Thanks